# How to fix a Div position from moving when another changes height dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have a 'bouncing loader' div, in which moves up and down on an infinite loop (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9emc9so9/)

However, if I place a button below it, (or anything else for that matter), it will also move in time to the animation effect.

Is there anyway of stopping this button from moving?

I have tried adding `margins`/`padding` on both, but they didn't work so I removed them.

the loader html:

```
<div class="loader" style="float:initial;">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<br />

<div>
    <button id="popupArea">Click here to invoke a popup window</button>
</div>
```

with the css being:

```
.loader {
    text-align: center;    
}
.loader span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
```

As always, any help/advice is welcomed.

Please note, I'm don't know jquery, so would like to avoid it as much as possible (hence i'm using asp MVC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```css
.loader {
  text-align: center;
}
.loader span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader" style="height:100px;">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <button id="popupArea">Click here to invoke a popup window</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following css attribute:

```
#popupArea {
   position:fixed;
   top:100px;//you can change the value as you wish
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9emc9so9/1/).

Comment: @NoName Why are you using `position: fixed;`??? You could achieve the same result if you set `height: 100px;` to `.loader` - http://jsfiddle.net/9emc9so9/3/

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about that. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put height at loader's div .

```
.loader {
    text-align: center;    
    height:85px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/9emc9so9/4/

Comment: for some reason, this didn't work for me (but Darshak's did?)

Comment: Maybe your css at this page.The jsfiddle is working though. Maybe Darshak's solution is better then!

Comment: the thing is, both (I thought) *should* have yielded the same result (but didn't?). But I can't actually remember where the loader came from, have had it stored in my files for yonks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just set the height for the span

Set **height: 100px;** in the loader

```
.loader {
    text-align: center; 
    height:100px;
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/9emc9so9/6/)

Comment: I was actually just trying this (as an alternative to accepted answer) - but for some reason it didn't work? Accepted answer adds a Height property to the div, whereas this adds it to css. Strange really...